# TextInputLayout changing EditText color to Red

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have come across this weird issue in which the `EditText` fields change color to `Red` in the start of an `Activity` like they change incase there is a `SetError`. Also, this does not happen everytime, only in some cases it appears. How do I fix this bug? Any help is appreciated.
Please refer image for more.
here is the code

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_name"
                    style="@style/my_style_textInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Name:"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/subHeading" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Here is the style:**

```
<style name="my_style_textInput" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    //hint color And Label Color in False State
    <!--<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/item_color</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/caption</item>
    //Label color in True State And Bar Color False And True State
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryAccent</item>
</style>
```

Please note, none of colorPrimary, colorAccent and item_color are red.Thank You.
[image: CHECK IMAGE HERE]

Comment: show your xml code of `text input layout`.

Comment: Do you have any style file in your application which you have applied to your activity?

Comment: yes, i do have style.

Comment: please update your question with `my_style_textInput` xml code...

Comment: updated, please check

Comment: hi @inkedTechie update your activity code aswell..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to customize the color.

Apply android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg" on your layout

```
<EditText
    android:la`enter code here`yout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/login_username"
    android:hint="@string/username_hint"
/>
```

After under drawable and create the file edittext_bg.xml and put this code inside.

```
<layer-list>
 <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <!-- Draw a 2dp width border around shape -->
         <stroke android:color="#ff1e0c" android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
 </item>
 <!-- Overlap the left, top and right border using background color  -->
  <item android:bottom="2dp">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#fffbce"/>
     </shape>
   </item>
```

Hope it helps you.